# Where do the values for JFileChooser.getTypeDescription(File f) come from

Tags: java

I have :

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

try {
    File tmp = File.createTempFile("tmp", "." + extension);
    System.out.println(chooser.getTypeDescription(tmp));
    tmp.delete();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

where the value of extension could be anything.  For example, extension 'mp3' gives a value of 'MP3 Format Sound'.

Where does 'MP3 Format Sound' come from?  Is it specific to the computer?

*edit: code clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer:

> Where does 'MP3 Format Sound' come
>   from? Is it specific to the computer?

The operating system. So yes, it is specific. 
`sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder` is the base class that gets extended depending on the target OS and provides the description.